# Query wp_postmeta into an array based on post_id

Tags: theme-development, database

I know this might be a simple question but can someone explain to me how to query the WP database and pull in all the "meta_key" and "meta_value" from "post_id" into an array? I have looked at code and tutorials but I still cant figure out how to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_post_meta( $post_id )` to retrieve all of the meta for a post. It will give you more than you need but you can filter it out after.

Here is the code reference - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how you can try something and once you post it works. I had tried the same code but couldn't get it to work before posting... "Power of Posting" right?